Drizzle relations
Is there way to get relation properties names from drizzle relation object.
Example
export const roleToPermissionRelations = relations(roleToPermission, ({ one }) => ({
    role: one(role, {
        fields: [roleToPermission.roleId],
        references: [role.id],
    }),
    permission: one(permission, {
        fields: [roleToPermission.permissionId],
        references: [permission.id],
    }),
}));










[role, permission]
Object.keys didnt work, and there is no nested props somewhere.
